# Unable to cast COM object of type 'Excel.WorksheetClass' for VSTO add-in

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel, vsto

I have tried a few things and am still getting this error. I am creating an excel VSTO using VBA and Visual Studio.

The way I have this setup is there is a button in the ribbon and that the user can click and it will go through and unlist all tables. I guess my issue lies with actually hooking onto the current active instance of Excel to loop through the worksheets.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ConvertAllTablesToRange.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{297DC8D9-EABD-45A1-BDEF-68AB67E5C3C3}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Here's what I've tried:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim wks As Worksheet, objList As ListObject

    For Each wks In Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook  ' ERROR LINE

        For Each objList In wks.ListObjects
            objList.Unlist()
        Next objList

    Next wks
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim wks As Worksheet, objList As ListObject
    Dim exApp As Excel.Application

    exApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    For Each wks In exApp.Worksheets
        For Each objList In wks.ListObjects
            objList.Unlist()
        Next objList
    Next wks
End Sub
```

Both of which throw the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there are 3 typecasting errors.

1- the `wks` variable needs to be set to `Excel.Worksheet` since `Worksheet` is `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Execl.Worksheet` while the type I need is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheet`

2- Same goes for the `objList` variable. Needs to be `Excel.ListObject` instead of `ListObject`

3- I need to search the collection `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`

That clears up all of the errors and allows the code to function without fail.

Answer (score 1):

In plain vanilla VBA which you can adapt to your requirements:

References to a Worksheet come from the Worksheets collection so code block #1 should have:

```
For Each wks In Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

In code block #2, assigning a Worksheets collection to an Application object makes no sense - two different, incompatible types. Try this instead:

```
Dim exApp As Excel.Application

' VBA requires Set for assigning any object type - remove
' the Set keyword if not needed in your approach
Set exApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application

For Each wks In exApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if there is a worksheet (isnot nothing)

```
Dim NativeWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook =
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
If NativeWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
Dim vstoWorkbook As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook =
    Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(NativeWorkbook)
End If
```

see more information  : [here msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc442981.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)

**EDIT** : here a working example but in C# , not in VB.NET, I think you can convert it because I'm not very efficient in VB.NET :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application XL =   Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = default(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook);
            xlWorkBook = XL.ActiveWorkbook;
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xs_loopVariable in xlWorkBook.Sheets)
            {
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject objList in xs_loopVariable.ListObjects)
                    {
                     objList.Unlist();
                    }
            }
```

Comment: And then use `vstoWorkbook` as the `In` in `For Each wks In vstoWorkbook`?

Comment: Tried this but same error, can you provide usage for this?

Comment: I think you must declare an Excel.Workbook variable, instantiate in with ActiveWorkbook before to use it in a loop. Something like :  1)Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook  ....  2)wkb =  Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook...3)  For Each wks In Wkb

Comment: Still no dice. Doing some more research on this now